# using PreviousPage functionalities without AutoEventWireup

Tags: c#, asp.net

G'day,

I'm using PreviousPage to get values from controls from another page like this:

```
sPORyear1 = PreviousPage.year1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
```

It works just fine, however I noticed that the events from C# Code Behind (ex. Button click) are not handled properly. I tried making a breakpoint inside the event and it doesn't stop.

After looking at my aspx I noticed this:

```
AutoEventWireup="true"
```

When I set that to false, the buttons work properly, but the PreviousPage functionality doesn't work anymore.

The button code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="export" runat="server" onserverclick="export_Click" Text="Export" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you are not getting the value for PreviousPage.year1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed it

[Button On Click event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012594/button-on-click-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 1):

When the AutoEventWireup is set to "False" Change the Page load Handler signature as below for the another page in which you are trying to access the value of previous page

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Please note that the access modifier should be `protected` not `Private` in case of `Autoeventwireup = "False"` Otherwise you will not be able to capture the `OnLoad` event

Comment: I suggested you to write protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    } in case of Autoeventwireup = false.