# Button On Click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

the on click event works in other pages though.

here's the header of the page i'm trying to get it to work:

```
<%@ Page Title="Report" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Report.aspx.cs" Inherits="Report" %>

    <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default.aspx">
```

and the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousPage == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
            // code..
```

when i click on it, it just redirects me to the PreviousPage. it also doesn't stop even when it has a breakpoint inside.

```
protected void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           //code
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code when some action is fired. Is some button action, hyperlink? I need more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Page Load, try using:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
      if (PreviousPage == null)
      {
          Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
      }

}
```

Comment: You mentioned that the page immediately goes to the other page when you click the button. This is because the button causes a postback. When this postback occurs, the PreviousPage value is null, so the page is redirected to your Default.aspx. You need to ensure that the page is not a postback so that it doesn't get redirected. The first time the page loads, it won't be considered a postback. If you click a button, change a drop down list (basically any event that communicates with the code-behind), that's when the postback occurs. Some Postback info here: http://dotnet.tekyt.info/?p=30

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more about hints.
Have you created in code Behind method to handle the click?

Something like `ButtonConfirm_Click(EventArgs e...`

Comment: yes, that's where i put the breakpoint.. protected void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

Comment: Strange behavior, in your code (aspx) can you paste the button Confirm declaration?

Comment: See @keyboardIp answer. He is correct! your click is gonna be a postback. And you don't want normal behavior of Page Load in postback. +1 for @keyboardIp